# Struts2 annotation not working on jboss EAP 7

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, jboss7.x

Recently we are planning to move our web app from JBoss 4.3 to JBoss 7. After a lot struggle we have successfully deployed the application.

But the problem begins with Struts2 annotations and Json calls. Struts 2 grid tag and Struts auto completer data is not loading into the JSP.

FYI we are using Java 8 and Struts 2 with Spring 3.0.

And below is the configuration we had in `Struts.xml` file

```
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/" />

  <constant name="struts.convention.exclude.parentClassLoader" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.convention.action.fileProtocols"  value="jar,vfsfile,vfszip" /> 
<constant name="struts.convention.action.includeJars" value=".*?/hope.*?jar(!/)" /> 

<constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.hope" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />  
<package name="showcase" extends="struts-default,json-default" namespace="/"></package>
```

`JsonAction.java` file below

```
@ParentPackage(value = "showcase")
public class NameTypeJson extends RegistrationAction {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private List<SelectItem>   regnameType          = null;
    @Actions({ 
        @Action(
        value="/regnametype",
            results={ @Result(name="success",type="json")
        })
        })
        public String loadnametype() throws Exception {

        //here logic                
                     return SUCCESS;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: No errors,but Struts autocompleters are not loading. @AleksandrM